# Pandas Add New Columns Based on Vaues from Different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, let's call it df1

```
id      level       a   b   c   d
1       One         1   3   4   4
1       two         1   3   4   
2       One         1   3   4   4
2       two         1   3   4
```

Then, there is a second dataframe, df2.

```
id      Type    Value
1       a      11
1       b      22
1       c      33
1       d      44      
2       a      91
2       b      92
2       c      93
2       d      94
```

What I would like is to compare the values from df1 and df2 to add new columns as follow.
Add new column called `type`_ `s` with values from from df2.

```
id      level       a   b   c   d   a_s  b_s  c_s  d_s
1       One         1   3   4   4   11   22   33   44
1       two         1   3   4       11   22   33   44   
2       One         1   3   4   4   91   92   93   94
2       two         1   3   4       91   92   93   94
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack, unstack df2 and merge with df

```
pd.merge(df,df2.set_index(['id','Type']).stack().unstack('Type').reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1']), how='left',on='id',suffixes=('', '_s'))

    id level  a  b  c    d  a_s  b_s  c_s  d_s
0   1   One  1  3  4  4.0   11   22   33   44
1   1   two  1  3  4  NaN   11   22   33   44
2   2   One  1  3  4  4.0   91   92   93   94
3   2   two  1  3  4  NaN   91   92   93   94
```

Or pivot df2 and merge

```
pd.merge(df,pd.pivot(df2, index='id', columns='Type').droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index(), how='left',on='id',suffixes=('', '_s'))
```

Comment: thanks!. but I am getting this error with both suggestions: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: Ok, `pd.merge(df,df2.pivot_table(index='id', columns='Type').droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index(), how='left',on='id',suffixes=('', '_s')) `

Comment: You certainly have duplicates in both `id` and `Type`. Use df.pivot_table because it has the capability of sorting hierarchical multindex. `pd.pivot` uses `Uses unique values from specified index`. Your sample fell short in that it didnt have duplicates in both `id` and `Type`. If that helps